# Help with PHP if / else statement

Tags: php, logic, referrer

On my site, forms are brought in via AJAX and checked against a sessionid. I know this is not optimal, but it's working for us. If the referrer doesn't have the session ID they are redirected back to "anotherpage". I need to allow some outside URL's access the form directly.
we set the sessionid on the page with the link to the form.

Here is what we have now on the form page:

```
<?php
$code = $_GET['sessionid'];
if(strcmp( $code , 'XXXXX'  ) != 0) {
    header("Location: http://www.domain.com/anotherpage.php");
} 
?>
```

I need to allow some outside domains direct access to the form page and am having issues with this:
(I'm putting it above the head tag on the form page)

```
<?php
    $code = $_GET['sessionid'];
    $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

    if(strcmp( $code , 'XXXXX' ) !=0) {
        header("Location: http://www.domain.com/anotherpage.php");
    } else {
        if (preg_match("/site1.com/",$referrer)) {
            header('Location: http://www.domain.com/desiredpage.php');
        }
    }
?>
```

this still bounces me back to "anotherpage.php" any ideas?

*************EDIT******************
thx for the help, it works ad I requested. Now I see what I asked wasn't entirely correct. This appends the URL with =sessionid?=XXXXX. This isn't an issue on my site because I'm loading the content with .jquery .load so the URL doesn't change. I don't want the sessionid to be visible, and now it is. Can I either a) "trim" the url somehow or b) separate the two functions so they are exclusive?

Comment: Doesn't the `else` warrant another condition? Shouldn't _that_ condition be evaluated _before_ the 'no-go redirect', or should the inner condition of `else` be embedded within the first, along with the redirect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(strcmp( $code , 'XXXXX' ) !=0) {
    if (preg_match("/site1.com/",$referrer)) {
        header('Location: http://www.domain.com/desiredpage.php');
    } else {
        header("Location: http://www.domain.com/anotherpage.php");
    }
}
```

Comment: @amosrivera - is there any way to do this w/o showing the appended url "domain.com/desiredpage.php?sesionid=XXXXX" in the browser address bar? on my site it's all done via jQuery .ajax > .load specific div's so the url is hidden

Comment: you could have a third page that takes care of the redirects, there you would have the if statement domain.com/redirect.php?sessionid=XXXX, is that what you mean?

Comment: @amosrivera - yes I think so, a separate third page that I tell external sites to use as <a href="externalpagescript.php"> and that page only has the referrer check?

Comment: no, i see that what you don't want to be visible is the session id, in that case you will have to do something different, like setting a cookie

Comment: @amosrivera - I see. Ill have to figure that out then. I really appreciate all your help, you answered the first question exactly as I asked it.

Answer (score 1):

As I read your post, you want anyone from the `preg_match` to get the desired page regardless of `sessionID` status, so you *don't* want to test sessionID first.

Start the `if block` with the `preg_match` test.

Comment: pls see edited question, I also don't want session id to show in url when coming from preg_match. when coming from page in site, url doesn't change as im using jQuery .ajax to .load content

Answer (score 1):

Your first `if` is checking to see if they don't have the `$code` and redirecting them. This will always be the case. You should probably check the `$referrer` first and then do the `$code` check.

Answer (score 1):

Try reverse if with else

```
<?php
    $code = $_GET['sessionid'];
    $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    if (preg_match("/site1.com/", $referrer)) {
        header('Location: http://www.domain.com/desiredpage.php');
    } else if (strcmp( $code , 'XXXXX' ) != 0) {
        header("Location: http://www.domain.com/anotherpage.php");
    }
?>
```

Comment: @jcubic - same answer above, and works. can PHP "trim" a url? Is there any way to do this w/o showing the appended url "domain.com/desiredpage.php?sesionid=XXXXX" in the browser address bar? on my site it's all done via jQuery .ajax > .load specific div's so the url is hidden

Comment: try `header('Location: http://www.domain.com/desiredpage.php?');` you can also use mod_rewrite in .htaccess file if you use apache.

Comment: using header('Location.....php?') didn't work. How would I use it in .htaccess? a 301 redirect to the page with an appended url? wouldn't that still show url?

Comment: In .htaccess if you put `?` in destination url it don't append query_string. `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !="sessionid=xxxx"` `RewriteRule .* /desiredpage.php? [R=301,L]`

Comment: @jcubic - sorry man, how would I make sure this only comes from the allowed domain? or do I do it in combination with the PHP on page?

Comment: use `HTTP_REFERER` variable `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !aloweddomain.com RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !="sessionid=xxxx" RewriteRule .* /desiredpage.php? [R=301,L]`

Comment: @jcubic - ok, so only the .htaccess. I have RewriteEngine On and several 301's - i have tried putting it above and below the 301's, always under RewriteEngine On and i get 500 internal server errors. I copied from "HTTP_REFERRER" to "[R=301, L]" replaced data with mine, session id and desired page

Comment: copy from `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}` to `[R=301,L]` but put new lines before `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` (you can't put newlines in comments) if this don't work then try to remove quotes from query string `!=sessionid=xxxx`

Comment: Now I can't access the site via direct url input. I rephrased question, maybe you can format answer so I don't screw it up here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5251526/trim-url-query-sting-with-htaccess

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not misunderstanding this, the problem is in the order in which you are checking things.

If you want to allow *some* referrers to access the site **even if they don't have the session id**, you have to check for that **before** checking for the session id. Otherwise, they will end up being treated just like everyone else.

You can either switch the order of the conditions (first check for the referrer and then check fo the session id) or check for the referrer inside the branch in which you already know the session id is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be in your regex, it should be:

```
if (preg_match("/site1\.com/",$referrer))
```

notice escaping the dot (.)