# trim url query string with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

On my site I use a session id when accessing a pages form content. The sessionid in the url isn't normally shown because it's accessed through jQuery .load so the url doesn't change. The page in reference above needs to be accessed by some outside domains directly.
I have used the following PHP at the top of the form page, to show the entire page.

```
<?php
    $code = $_GET['sessionid'];
    $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

    if(strcmp( $code , 'XXXXX' ) !=0) {
    if (preg_match("/alloweddomain.com/",$referrer)) {
header('Location: http://www.mydomain.com/desiredpage.php?sessionid=XXXXX');
} else {
header("Location: http://www.mydomain.com/otherpage.php");
        }
    }
?>
```

Is there a way with .htaccess to remove the session ID? I've tried the following but get 500 Internal Server Errors.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
"lots of 301 redirects"
HTTP_REFERER variable RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !aloweddomain.com RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !="sessionid=XXXXX" RewriteRule .* /desiredpage.php? [R=301,L]
```

****EDIT*************
used this, filling in the appropriate details

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !**aloweddomain.com** [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !=sessionid=**XXXXX**
RewriteRule .* /**desiredpage**.php? [R=301,L]
```

just get FF error that it can't complete redirect

Comment: http://briancray.com/2010/03/18/htaccess-hack-remove-url-query-strings/

Comment: "THIS WILL BREAK ANY FUNCTIONALITY THAT DEPENDS ON QUERY STRINGS" - im guessing that would be my normal use of session ID?

Answer (score 1):

you forget newlines

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !aloweddomain.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !=sessionid=XXXXX
RewriteRule .* /desiredpage.php? [R=301,L]
```

This will redirect all url's that don't came from aloweddomain.com or don't have Query_String. I forget about `[OR]` if there is nor `[OR]` then then the two conditions must be true.

and if desiredpage.php is simply page that show that you can't access the site then you can put 403 Forbidden instead of redirect

```
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

If you want to call it from AJAX or custom domain.

```
if (preg_match('/domain.com/', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) || 
    $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest') {
   // allowed
   header('Location: http://www.mydomain.com/desiredpage.php');
} else {
   // not allowed
   header('Location: http://www.mydomain.com/otherpage.php');
}
```

code for `desiredpage.php`

```
if (!(preg_match('/domain.com/', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ||
    $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest')) {
   header('Location: http://www.mydomain.com/otherpage.php');
}
```

Comment: and this won't affect the entire site, just that page right? Nope doesn't work, I just get a FF message "Problem loading Page...redirecting in a way ff cannot resolve"

Comment: How about if I just check to see if it's either an xmlHTTPrequest (mine) or from allowed domain? that would get rid of the stupid sessionid right?

Comment: You can't check for custom headers in .htaccess but I put solution in php.

Comment: But if you put redirect in php script then user can check destination page and access it normally and bypass your check. Best way is to not redirect to other pages but do your stuff in the same file.

Comment: @jcubic - real close  now. the only way i could get it to load page was with the page name and extension added to '/domain.com/page.php' 
Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier 'd' in /home/xxx/public_html/desiredpage.php on line 2

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/xxx/public_html/desiredpage.php:2) in /home/xxx/public_html/desiredpage.php on line 8

Comment: it seems that you change regex in `preg_match` to something like `/domain.com/d....` or `/..../domain.com/` if you put slashes inside regular expressions you must escape them. regular expression must be `"/.../misx"` where `misx` are alowed flags.

Comment: @jcubic - man this is nuts. it loads the correct page, but with those errors /domain.com"/"page.php is how I have it now

Comment: If I'm understand correctly, you what only to call it from "domain.com/page.php" page if so then use `preg_match("/domain.com\/page.php/", $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ||`, but this will only work if you have link on page.php to the page with this code. And if you want to use this script if it's on different server like localhost you can use `HTTP_HOST` instead of `HTTP_REFERER`.

Comment: yes, we will provide the other domain with the link. I will know exactly what page the link is on, complete url etc.

Comment: here's the error i keep getting. "The page isn't redirecting properly

      

      
      
      

      
        
        

          

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

        


        
        


    *   This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept
          cookies."

Comment: Maybe you have "recursive infinite redirect", is the page desiredpage.php is the one that have this redirect? In Firefox this message is shown when page `test.php` have `header("Location: test.php")`.

Comment: yes "desiredpage.php" has all of the code a the top. should I place the code in a separate page

Comment: Then you need only one `if` clause.

Comment: @jcubic - alrighty ill give it a shot. I really appreciate all the time you spent helping me with this.